# select where field equal 0 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in MySQL Database :

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| ID | NAME  | idcountry |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | Jack  |         1 |
|  2 | Simon |         1 |
|  3 | Peter |         0 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

I want display all users who have a idcountry equal a ZERO :

```
select name from users where idcountry = 0
```

but the query returned an empty result, but if I want to display all users who have a idcountry equal a 1

```
select name from users where idcountry = 1
```

the query works great, So what is the problem, I  understood nothing

Comment: Is idcountry defined as a varchar by chance?

Comment: No is integer, and i'm sure

Comment: What does `DESCRIBE users;` show?

Comment: @RocketHazmat : idcountry is int(11)

Comment: It may be problems with column typing, but I've run into the issue of not getting the results I expect when 0's get passed unquoted.

Comment: Just tried and it runs fine. See this demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26b49/1